# How can I match rows in two excel spreadsheets (rows in different orders and column names slightly different) and use this to update first sheet?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, spreadsheet, string-matching

I have two excel spreadsheets (A and B) that I need to compare using a python script. I need to update the string in each cell of column 16 of spreadsheet A using information located in column 20 of spreadsheet B (these columns have the same name in both sheets, lets call these the "results" columns). The problem is that some of the other columns 1-15 in spreadsheet A and B are named slightly differently (but data in columns 1-15 are identical between sheets **only when rows are in same order**), and the rows in spreadsheet A **are in a different order** than the rows in spreadsheet B. I would like to know how I can match each row in spreadsheet A to its respective row in spreadsheet B and then use that to compare and update the "results" column of spreadsheet A using string values in "results" column of spreadsheet B. All rows of spreadsheet A and B are unique. The extra 4 columns in spreadsheet B are not needed for matching of rows, as they are redundant and the rows of spreadsheet B are still unique without these 4 columns.

Example of Data in Spreadsheet A:

| Date | Color | Name | Animal | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4/1/2021 | Orange | Fred | Rat | Pass |
| 2/15/2021 | Blue | Albert | Monkey | Fail |
| 3/18/2021 | Purple | Joe | Rat | Not Evaluated |

Example of Data in Spreadsheet B:

| Date | Color | Fst Name | Number | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18-Mar-2021 | Purple | Joe | one | Not Evaluated |
| 1-Apr-2021 | Orange | Fred | two | Pass |
| 15-Feb-2021 | Blue | Albert | one | Pass |

Example of the **desired** output:

| Date | Color | Name | Animal | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-Apr-2021 | Orange | Fred | Rat | Pass |
| 15-Feb-2021 | Blue | Albert | Monkey | Pass |
| 18-Mar-2021 | Purple | Joe | Rat | Not Evaluated |

So far I have been able to get Spreadsheet A dates in the same format as Spreadsheet B dates using the following code:

```
df["DateTime Recorded"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"]).dt.strftime("%d-%b-%y")
```

**I would like to know how I can match each row in spreadsheet A to its respective row in spreadsheet B by matching strings in different columns and then use that to compare and update the "results" column of spreadsheet A using string values in "results" column of spreadsheet B.**

Comment: Could you share sample data and your code so far as text not images?

Comment: Unfortunately it is confidential, but I'm more after the process here than anything, specifically for matching rows, anyways

Comment: I see; in that case, could you generate some representative sample data, as well as runnable code (what you've tried so far), and corresponding expected output? We can't really debug plain English descriptions :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello, I have added some more information :)